# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in datatables when populate record from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

im able to display my database records into html table. But when i want to using jquery datatables, on the inspect element there is an error said:

> cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I am using asp.net. Here my code:

**Product.aspx**

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead class="thead-inverse" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <th>ID Product</th>
        <th>Nama Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Harga</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr><%=GetData()%></tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Product.aspx.cs**

```
 public string GetData()
 {   
      string data ="";
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-FSET3FF; Initial Catalog=INOVA_data; User Id=sa; Password=Copoe113"))
      {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id_barang, nama_barang, quantity, harga from Barang"))
          {
              cmd.Connection = con;
              cmd.Connection.Open();

              using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  if (sdr.HasRows)
                  {
                     while (sdr.Read())
                     {
                         int id = sdr.GetInt32(0);
                         string nama = sdr.GetString(1);
                         int qty = sdr.GetInt32(2);
                         string harga = sdr.GetString(3);

                         data += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + nama + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + harga + "</td></tr>";
                      }
               }

            }
         }
         return data;
     }
 }
```

**Jquery Script**

```
script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datatable').dataTable();
        });

     </script>
```

Comment: Seems you need to make jQuery ajax call instead directly using `ready` event to load datatable. Also ensure that total passed columns match the structure defined in `columns.data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the right way of using datatable. However, for your code works. I think here is your error

```
 <tr><%=GetData()%></tr>
```

You should remove `<tr>` tag because you have generated it in your c# code. It should be

```
 <%=GetData()%>
```

For standard way of using datatable. You may refer https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html